# How to skip the validation of texts within an xml tag?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, xml-parsing

I am getting xml downloaded from bugzilla in this format:

```
<bugzilla>
     <bug>
          <bug_id>111</bug_id>
          <short_desc>text 1 & 2</short_desc>
      </bug>
      <bug>
          <bug_id>222</bug_id>
          <short_desc>text 2 <this is a short desc> </short_desc>
     </bug>
</bugzilla>
```

As you can see, when i am trying to parse this using jaxb parser, its failing with two reasons:

1. for & within the first  tag (it needs to be changed to `&amp;` 
   Error message: `The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.`
2. same case for `<this is a short desc>` text. Error message `The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.`

But what i dont understand is both these are contents of valid tags. So why validation logic is running for such contents. In the second case, its not just a single tag right as `<thisisashortdesc>`, which can throw actual valid error saying the closing tag missing. but this case has spaces between.

Find the code been used belowg:

File file = new File("C:\test\file.xml");

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bugzilla.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Bugzilla bugzillaReport = (Bugzilla) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Anyways to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's not validation, it's well-formedness. That's not about verifying that some constraints are respected, that's about is it possible to read this or not. XML documents must be well-formed, otherwise the parser reaches a state where it is unable to know what data is supposed to be represented and how to continue parsing from there, in other words it becomes incapable to do the job expected of it, so there's no point pretending. Validation can be skipped and often is. Well-formedness is obligatory as it is part of doing parsing at all.

Comment: @kumesana thanks for the info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware, valid XML must be parsed, as there is no fuzzy matching as in HTML. The standard solution is to place a `<![CDATA[....]]>`. (*CDATA* stands for *character data*.)

```
<short_desc><![CDATA[text 1 & 2]]></short_desc>
<short_desc><![CDATA[text 2 <this is a short desc> ]]></short_desc>
```

This is cumbersome, and the question is whether usage still works, when a text instead of a CData is expected. And creating the correct XML is probably easier. Apache commons also has a `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(String)` for that purpose.

Try it (CDATA) first.

```
String xml = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\test\\file.xml")),
         StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\">\n" + xml;
xml = xml.replace("<short_desc>", "<short_desc><![CDATA[");
xml = xml.replace("</short_desc>", "]]></short_desc>");
jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Notice that a backslash `\` must be self-escaped in a java String.

A java 9 repair:

```
xml = xml.replaceAll("(?s)<short_desc>(.*)</short_desc>",
        matchResult -> "<short_desc>"
                       + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(matchResult.group(1))
                       + "</short_desc>");
```

or without apache common lang StringEscapeUtils:

```
xml = xml.replaceAll("(?s)<short_desc>(.*)</short_desc>",
        matchResult -> "<short_desc>"
                       + matchResult.group(1)
                             .replace("&", "&amp;")
                             .replace("\"", "&quot;")
                             .replace("<", "&lt;")
                             .replace(">", "&gt;")
                       + "</short_desc>");
```

Comment: It worked. I dont have control over modifying the xml file. so like you suggested i enclosed the tag contents within CDATA tag and it worked fine. Thanks a lot. Can you please explain how and why CDATA tags are skipped by the parser or how the contents within the cdata tag is considered.

Comment: The CDATA section is delimited by `]]>` and is a way to include unprocessed text (that _should_ be checked for not containing "]]>"). In the DOM tree it not a #text node, but its own one. However most XML API provide a _get text content_, collecting several consecutive #text nodes and such. Hence it _can_ work.